# Paging does not remember last page viewed

Tags: feature-request, bug

Paging does not remember the last position. If you are on 3rd page of the questions and open a question (in to detail) then click back button - this always lands on very first page of the questions. The expected behavior should be on click of back button it should land on 3rd page( or what ever page you last viewed).

Comment: words do matter. I am using paging and the issue already reported using 'backward navigation'.

Comment: Clicking the back button is "backward navigation".